# Comparing confidence scores from decision_function() for scikit-learn LinearSVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, svm

I am using scikit-learn's LinearSVC SVM implementation to perform tagging of text. I have about 100 classifiers trained for different tags. I now want to rank the tags in order of their similarity with the model. I will need to compare confidence scores from decision_function() across these classifiers. Can anyone confirm if I can do that? What do the scores from decision_function() actually mean?

Comment: The scores are the signed distances from the SVMs' hyperplanes.

Comment: Yes, but any idea if I can compare these across classifiers?

Comment: A priori, I'd say *no*. But I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you get anywhere with this?